# Using python to extract parts of a data file

Tags: python, regex, substring

Below is a sample data which is automatically recorded from a sensor placed in the soil.

DATA:

```
13:00:\0xca~\0x00Z\0x90\0x00\0x13\0xa2\0x00@\0xc5A\0x95B\0x81\0x01<=>\0x80\0x03#400567223#Node 5#0#SOIL:0-8-0+0#SOILT:20.00#STR:Fri, 16/12/09, 

13:00:00#\0x8c~\0x00`\0x90\0x00\0x13\0xa2\0x00@\0xc5B/\0xce\0xa6\0x01<=>\0x80\0x03#394750562#Node 6#0#SOIL:108-104-105+110#SOILT:130.00#STR:Fri, 16/12/09
```

We need to extract only portions of the data to further use it for prediction purposes.

The required format of data should contain the following details:

```
13:00:Node 5#0#SOIL:0-8-0+0#SOILT:20.00#STR:Fri, 16/12/09
```

I have tried using python and regex, but im only able to get one part of the string and only for one single line. Im supposed to do it for a large text file.

Below is the code i have tried, please excuse me for the bad code, im just a beginner.

```
import re
filename = '2016lastday.txt'
pattern  = 'Node(.*)$'
new_file = []


with open(filename, 'r') as f:
     lines = f.readlines()


for line in lines:
    match = re.search(pattern, line)
    if match:

       new_line = match.group() + '\n'
       print new_line
       new_file.append(new_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there :

```
import re
filename = '2016lastday.txt'
pattern  = re.compile('(\d\d:\d\d:).*(?<=#)(Node.*?\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)')
new_lines = []


with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = re.search(pattern, line)
        if match:
           new_line = match.group(1) + match.group(2) + '\n'
           new_lines.append(new_line)

print new_lines
# ['13:00:Node 5#0#SOIL:0-8-0+0#SOILT:20.00#STR:Fri, 16/12/09\n', '13:00:Node 6#0#SOIL:108-104-105+110#SOILT:130.00#STR:Fri, 16/12/09\n']
```

Note that naming variables is very important. `new_file` isn't a file in your example, it's just a list of strings.

Comment: I tried the above code, the output is only from a single line in the middle of the file and not the entire text file, i'm not able to iterate from the beginning.